# Left div scrolls and right div stretches the layout height / cross browser compatible?

Tags: css, cross-browser, height, html

I am wondering whether it is possible to get such a layout cross browser compatible. I want to have two divs side by side inside a container div. The content of the right div should stretch the height of the whole layout, or in other words stretch the height of the container div.

In the left div, I'd like to have a header and a footer div with fixed heights. In between these two divs, I would like to have a scrollable content div. This div should stretch as the content of the right div grows.

I got this to work in Google Chrome here: http://cssdesk.com/PFNuX

However, it does not work in IE and FF.

I tried various solutions with floating divs, with tables, with divs displaying as table etc. but none of my solutions worked properly. Only the above solution works and it only works in Chrome (I haven't tried Opera and Safari).

My guess, is that I could get this to work in all browsers by using some jQuery, or some JavaScript, but I haven't tried that yet. I would prefer a solution that works in all modern browsers with CSS only and no JS.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Javascript to resize the `<div>` to fit the content.